# PyTorch : predict single example

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, backpropagation

Following the example from:

https://github.com/jcjohnson/pytorch-examples

This code trains successfully:

```
# Code in file tensor/two_layer_net_tensor.py
import torch

device = torch.device('cpu')
# device = torch.device('cuda') # Uncomment this to run on GPU

# N is batch size; D_in is input dimension;
# H is hidden dimension; D_out is output dimension.
N, D_in, H, D_out = 64, 1000, 100, 10

# Create random input and output data
x = torch.randn(N, D_in, device=device)
y = torch.randn(N, D_out, device=device)

# Randomly initialize weights
w1 = torch.randn(D_in, H, device=device)
w2 = torch.randn(H, D_out, device=device)

learning_rate = 1e-6
for t in range(500):
  # Forward pass: compute predicted y
  h = x.mm(w1)
  h_relu = h.clamp(min=0)
  y_pred = h_relu.mm(w2)

  # Compute and print loss; loss is a scalar, and is stored in a PyTorch Tensor
  # of shape (); we can get its value as a Python number with loss.item().
  loss = (y_pred - y).pow(2).sum()
  print(t, loss.item())

  # Backprop to compute gradients of w1 and w2 with respect to loss
  grad_y_pred = 2.0 * (y_pred - y)
  grad_w2 = h_relu.t().mm(grad_y_pred)
  grad_h_relu = grad_y_pred.mm(w2.t())
  grad_h = grad_h_relu.clone()
  grad_h[h < 0] = 0
  grad_w1 = x.t().mm(grad_h)

  # Update weights using gradient descent
  w1 -= learning_rate * grad_w1
  w2 -= learning_rate * grad_w2
```

How can I predict a single example ? My experience thus far is utilising feedforward networks using just `numpy`. After training a model I utilise forward propagation but for a single example :

`numpy` code snippet where `new` is the output value I'm attempting to predict:

```
new = np.asarray(toclassify) 
Z1 = np.dot(weight_layer_1, new.T) + bias_1 
sigmoid_activation_1 = sigmoid(Z1) 
Z2 = np.dot(weight_layer_2, sigmoid_activation_1) + bias_2 
sigmoid_activation_2 = sigmoid(Z2)
```

`sigmoid_activation_2` contains the predicted vector attributes

Is the idiomatic PyTorch way same?  Use forward propagation in order to make a single prediction?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The code you posted is a simple demo trying to reveal the inner mechanism of such deep learning frameworks. These frameworks, including PyTorch, Keras, Tensorflow and many more automatically handle the forward calculation, the tracking and applying gradients for you as long as you defined the network structure. However, the code you showed still try to do these stuff manually. That's the reason why you feel cumbersome when predicting one example, because you are still doing it from scratch.

In practice, we will define a model class inherited from `torch.nn.Module` and initialize all the network components (like neural layer, GRU, LSTM layer etc.) in the `__init__` function, and define how these components interact with the network input in the `forward` function.

Taken the example from the page you've provided:

```
# Code in file nn/two_layer_net_module.py
import torch

class TwoLayerNet(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, D_in, H, D_out):
        """
        In the constructor we instantiate two nn.Linear modules and 
        assign them as
        member variables.
        """
        super(TwoLayerNet, self).__init__()
        self.linear1 = torch.nn.Linear(D_in, H)
        self.linear2 = torch.nn.Linear(H, D_out)

    def forward(self, x):
        """
        In the forward function we accept a Tensor of input data and we must return
        a Tensor of output data. We can use Modules defined in the constructor as
        well as arbitrary (differentiable) operations on Tensors.
        """
        h_relu = self.linear1(x).clamp(min=0)
        y_pred = self.linear2(h_relu)
        return y_pred

# N is batch size; D_in is input dimension;
# H is hidden dimension; D_out is output dimension.
N, D_in, H, D_out = 64, 1000, 100, 10

# Create random Tensors to hold inputs and outputs
x = torch.randn(N, D_in)
y = torch.randn(N, D_out)

# Construct our model by instantiating the class defined above.
model = TwoLayerNet(D_in, H, D_out)

# Construct our loss function and an Optimizer. The call to 
model.parameters()
# in the SGD constructor will contain the learnable parameters of the two
# nn.Linear modules which are members of the model.
loss_fn = torch.nn.MSELoss(size_average=False)
optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=1e-4)
for t in range(500):
    # Forward pass: Compute predicted y by passing x to the model
    y_pred = model(x)

    # Compute and print loss
    loss = loss_fn(y_pred, y)
    print(t, loss.item())

    # Zero gradients, perform a backward pass, and update the weights.
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()
```

The code defined a model named TwoLayerNet, it initializes two linear layers in the `__init__` function and further defines how these two linears interact with the input `x` in the `forward` function.

Having the model defined, we can perform a single feed-forward operation as follows. Say `xu` contains a single unseen example:

```
xu = torch.randn(D_in)
```

Then this performs the prediction:

```
y_pred = model(torch.atleast_2d(xu))
```

Comment: thanks, "y_pred = model(x)" executes forward propagation over x , not a single instance. How does this answer question as I'm attempting to predict a new unseen example ? In other words "y_pred = model(x)" predicts all examples in x , not a single example ?

Comment: seems PyTorch has made this "too simple" :) , appears to achieve expected behaviour : "y_pred = model(x[0])"

Comment: Yes, "y_pred = model(x)" predicts all the examples in x. I'm not sure what's your use-case of predicting just one single example. You could either do it the way you did or wrap the single example up in a higher dimension and then pass it through the model instance.

Comment: my use-case is to predict a single unseen example after the model has been trained

Comment: Say x_unseen = torch.Tensor([1, 2, 3, .3, .2, ..., .1])
where len(x_unseen) equals D_in.
Then y_pred = model(torch.atleast_2d(x_unseen))